.NET application deployed in Azure DevOps Pipeline shows 404 error
I have an application with frontend in React js (Vite) and backend in .NET and Node and I am trying to setup a pipeline for the deployment.
My project structure is as below
`Project

reactwithasp.client //Frontend Dir
reactwithasp.server //Backend Dir
.csproj
.sln`

And my YAML file is as below:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - Test  # Change this to the branch to trigger the pipeline on
 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'  # Use a Windows agent for .NET solution
 
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'  # Change to 'Debug' if required
  PUBLISH_DIRECTORY: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
 
steps:
 
 
  # Step 1: Checkout code from the repository
  - checkout: self
    displayName: 'Checkout Code'
 
  # Step 2: Install Node.js and dependencies for React client
  - script: |
      echo "NODE_ENV="
      npm install -g node@21.7.2 vite@5.4.10
      npm ci
    displayName: 'Install Node.js and Vite'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/reactwithasp.client
 
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSource: 'spec'
      versionSpec: '21.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  
  # Step 2: Verify Node version
  - script: |
      node -v
      npm -v
    displayName: 'Verify Node.js and npm Versions'
 
 
  - task: UseNode@1
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '21.x'
    displayName: 'Use Node.js 21'
 
  # Step 3: Use .NET Core SDK
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '8.x'  # Adjust to match your project's .NET SDK version
    displayName: 'Install .NET SDK'
 
  # Step 4: Restore NuGet packages for .NET solution
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*.sln'
    displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
 
  # Step 5: Install React dependencies
  - script: npm install
    displayName: 'Install React Dependencies'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/reactwithasp.client
 
  # Step 6: Build the React client
  - script: npm run build
    displayName: 'Build React App'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/reactwithasp.client
 
  # Step 7: Copy React client build output directly to publish directory
  - script: |
      cp -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/reactwithasp.client/dist/* $(PUBLISH_DIRECTORY)
    displayName: 'Copy React Build to Publish Directory'
 
  # Step 8: Build the .NET solution
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*.sln'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(PUBLISH_DIRECTORY)\\"'
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    displayName: 'Build .NET Solution'
 
  # Step 9: Publish .NET build artifacts
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(PUBLISH_DIRECTORY)'
      artifactName: 'dotnetBuild'
    displayName: 'Publish .NET Build Artifacts'
 
  # Step 10: Deploy to Azure Web App, pointing to wwwroot
  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
      azureSubscription: 'abc-PCS'
      appType: 'webApp'
      WebAppName: 'abcpcs'
      packageForLinux: '$(PUBLISH_DIRECTORY)/*.zip'  # Adjust if path or filename differs
    displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'

Figured out, the build files are not getting copied to the wwwroot folder, hence the website shows 404 error.
My directory paths:
System.DefaultWorkingDirectory: D:\a\1\s Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory: D:\a\1\a
Where as the wwwroot path is /c/home/site/wwwroot
Not able to find what the issue is and been stuck with this from days now. Please help.
Earlier there was issue with vite and it was throwing error 'vite' is not recognized as internal or external command and after installing vite it moved ahead one step.
Now I am getting below error:
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
npm run build
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\9abfa463-0928-4d82-b16a-f525c9bc3fca.cmd""
 
> reactwithasp.client@0.0.0 build D:\a\1\s\reactwithasp.client
> vite build
 
D:\a\1\s\reactwithasp.client\node_modules\vite\bin\vite.js:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
       ^
 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactwithasp.client@0.0.0 build: `vite build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactwithasp.client@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2024-10-31T19_00_52_549Z-debug.log
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Build React App

**UPDATE: even after trying HTTPS=false in vite.config.js and setting VITE_HTTPS=false in yaml.
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
npm run build
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\fcbec466-9955-4d29-8573-5410e178f18c.cmd""
 
> reactwithasp.client@0.0.0 build
> vite build
 
There was an error exporting the HTTPS developer certificate to a file.
failed to load config from D:\a\1\s\reactwithasp.client\vite.config.js
error during build:
Error: Could not create certificate.
    at file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/vite.config.js.timestamp-1730747332612-efccc51bf23a2.mjs:27:11
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-94_H5fT6.js:68112:21)
    at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-94_H5fT6.js:67967:28)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-94_H5fT6.js:67579:28)
    at async build (file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-94_H5fT6.js:66729:20)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///D:/a/1/s/reactwithasp.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:842:9)
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Build React App with HTTPS Disabled



Have you added WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0 in your Web app Configuration? 2. Please build your app on your local machine and deploy it using az webapp deploy, then check what's the result. After that we can know whether the issue is related to your app itself. 3. What's your actual issue? 404 error in the app or npm error in "Build React App" step? Is "Build React App" step successful before deployment?


If I deploy locally and even through visual studio, the build succeeds. But with the devops, its failing at the npm build step (Earlier the yaml file was not correct in my knowledge so build was successful but I was getting 404 error because no files were getting copied to wwwroot but with some tweaks in yaml as above, the build is failing now)


What's the version of your NodeJs when you build locally? 2. To know whether it's related to the environment in the pipeline, you can set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine where you can build and deploy your app successfully, then use this agent to run the pipeline.


In local its 21.7.2 and I have put the same version while installing node in yaml and even tried with 14.80.0 but the error is now with HTTPS certificate. I have updated my initial question with the latest error, please have a look.

Hi @Priyabrata, can you have a try to set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine where you can build and deploy your app successfully, then use this agent to run the pipeline? Currently, the error message in the log is not clear. If the pipeline works on this self-hosted, the issue may be related to environment in the MS-hosted agent, then we can focus on the configuration of the pipeline. If it fails, go to check the complete log on your self-hosted agent as mentioned in the log. To focus on one issue, I would suggest you back to the old version without editing HTTPS.

If you really cannot use a self-hosted agent, enable verbose logs and check if there is any detailed error message.

Seems the information you provided files are being copied to PUBLISH_DIRECTORY
which is pointing to "d:\a\1\a but you need to make sure that files are properly zipped and deployed to "~\wwwroot" directory


Script: |
cd $(PUBLISH_DIRECTORY)
zip -r ../publish.zip
DisplayName: "Zip create from published Directory"


Update the deployment task

'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish.zip'

Ensuring your build outputs are zipped and copied correctly will hopefully solve your 404 issues. If Still exists then please check the logs again. Thanks

I tried but the error is now with HTTPS certificate. I have updated my initial question with the latest error, please have a look.
